# HQL injection/findAll with query and sorting

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

In my application, the query is being built by appending the first part(where clause) with the second part(order by) using a separate script like QueryBuilder.groovy and hence the order by part is prone to HQL injection which can't be sanitized by using Named Parameters. Therefore, I want to use findAll to retrieve a set of records by passing it a query and sorting and paging parameters separately. I saw an implementation like this:

Book.findAll(query, [max: 10, offset: 5])

but I want to pass sorting parameters as well. Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'oder by ...' to your query:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#hql -> Pagination and Sorting